# Recovery of corrupt .mov file from dash cam

Tags: video, codec, media

Yesterday on the way to work I was run into by a truck. I felt relaxed that I had my dash cam running only to find out last night when I tried to retrieve the commute file that it could not be opened.

There are lots of .mov files on the sd card but 50% or more can not be opened (and do not display a thumbnail in Mac either.)

[image]

I have tried to open in; Quicktime, VLC, Final Cut Pro and the guys at work who edit videos have tried also in various applications. I've also tried a few 'repair' apps and even Handbrake (somebody suggested to try to convert it to mp4.)

When I open the file in media info, I see this;

> General
>   Complete name : /Users/cbiggins/Desktop/AMBA3984.MOV
>   Format : MPEG-4
>   Format profile : QuickTime
>   Codec ID : qt   0000.00 (qt  )
>   File size : 302 MiB

If I open one of the functional files, I see this;

> General
>   Complete name : /Volumes/NO NAME/DCIM/100VIDEO/AMBA3957.MOV
>   Format : MPEG-4
>   Format profile : QuickTime
>   Codec ID : qt   0000.00 (qt  )
>   File size : 17.8 MiB
>   Duration : 9s 710ms
>   Overall bit rate mode : Constant
>   Overall bit rate : 15.4 Mbps
>   Encoded date : UTC 1970-01-03 14:29:27
>   Tagged date : UTC 1970-01-03 14:29:27
>   AMBA :

Plus **big** sections for video and audio (which i left out for readabilities sake.)

I don't know what is going on and considering the file is over 300mb, there is *something* in it. I just really need help recovering this file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recover the file using Yodot Mov repair.

I'm going to use that and a combination of untrunc for the rest of the files.